# Google Cloud Platform: API calls concurrency limitation errors

Tags: api, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

When I try to do Instance SimulateMaintenanceEvent by `gcloud compute instances simulate-maintenance-event` command from linux VM (in GCP) I get one of the following errors:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.compute.instances.simulate-maintenance-event) Maintenance cannot be simulated on this instance due to temporary concurrency limitations.  Please try again in a few minutes.
```

or

```
ERROR: (gcloud.compute.instances.simulate-maintenance-event) Internal error. Please try again or contact Google Support. (Code: '-238115167244891842')
```

Interesting thing is that errors happen far more frequently while working in `us-central1` region unlike in `us-east1`. No service account is used.

According to page https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/api-rate-limits for SimulateMaintenanceEvent requests there are:

- Rate per project: 2 requests/second
- Rate per user: 2 requests/second
- Quota buckets are refilled every 100 seconds

I do API calls once in ~13min and retry in 5 mins if it fails, however it keeps failing several times and succeeds very seldom.

Any ideas why this is happening? Any solutions?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have a wild guess ... The maintenance that we are talking about here is maintenance to the GCP framework itself such that if Google has to update the code  that "IS" a Compute Instance, it can do this transparently to what appears to be YOUR compute instances.  We may assume that this happens "relatively" infrequently.  What if the period (it might be days) during which you were testing, Google happened to be performing an update ... it might "restrict" your testing to ensure that the maximum resources are available to do the NEEDED migration?  Simulate may be "best effort" availability.

Comment: @Kolban So you assume that when I try to simulate migration, it coincides with the case when Google does some updates and has to perform migration itself for that purposes.  Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Yes sir ... but it is a wild guess and PLEASE don't take it as the final word.  It is merely a hypothesis to try and explain what you are seeing.  If you could, keep trying and see if it really is a "transient thing".

Comment: Understood.. Thank you. Will try to keep you informed.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to limits (which are not changeable), Google services are also restricted by quotas. Quotas are extendable upon request. Have you checked if it's not quota you are limited by?

Take a look at the following article which shows how to check your quotas.

https://cloud.google.com/docs/quota

Comment: There are only 3 quotas regarding SimulateMaintenanceEvent:

  1. Instance SimulateMaintenanceEvent requests per day

  2. Instance SimulateMaintenanceEvent requests per 100 seconds

  3. Instance SimulateMaintenanceEvent requests per 100 seconds per user.

I am afraid non of them regards to concurrency limitation (besides non of them have been exceeded so far.)